# Ruby/Rails - How to convert seconds to time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, time, timestamp, seconds

I need to perform the following conversion:

```
0     -> 12.00AM
1800  -> 12.30AM
3600  -> 01.00AM
...
82800 -> 11.00PM
84600 -> 11.30PM
```

I came up with this:

```
(0..84600).step(1800){|n| puts "#{n.to_s} #{Time.at(n).strftime("%I:%M%p")}"}
```

which gives me the wrong time, because Time.at(n) expects n to be number of seconds from epoch:

```
0     -> 07:00PM
1800  -> 07:30PM
3600  -> 08:00PM
...
82800 -> 06:00PM
84600 -> 06:30PM
```

What would be the most optimal, time zone independent solution for this transformation?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The simplest one-liner simply ignores the date:

```
Time.at(82800).utc.strftime("%I:%M%p")

#-> "11:00PM"
```

Comment: NB: If someone came here looking for an answer to get a way to convert any number of seconds (even high counts which spans days) into an ever increasing HH:MM:SS counter (not just limited to a 24 hour span), then this answer is not the solution to that. Ignoring the date, like this answer suggest, will make the HH counter be reset to 00 whenever going across day boundaries.

Comment: @Magne Your note was meant for me. Now, do you have a suggestion for a solution for an ever increasing HH:MM:SS?

Comment: @JoshuaPinter yes, I found my solution and posted it as an answer here for you now: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65166238/380607

Comment: Not working if hours is > 24

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this is better than

```
(Time.local(1,1,1) + 82800).strftime("%I:%M%p")


def hour_minutes(seconds)
  Time.at(seconds).utc.strftime("%I:%M%p")
end


irb(main):022:0> [0, 1800, 3600, 82800, 84600].each { |s| puts "#{s} -> #{hour_minutes(s)}"}
0 -> 12:00AM
1800 -> 12:30AM
3600 -> 01:00AM
82800 -> 11:00PM
84600 -> 11:30PM
```

Stephan

Comment: It's nice and short, but I think "toClock" does the more direct calculations and looks more reliable. Except "toClock" should reject negative inputs, and perform "% 86400" on the input.

Answer (score 2):

Two offers:

The elaborate DIY solution:

```
def toClock(secs)
  h = secs / 3600;  # hours
  m = secs % 3600 / 60; # minutes
  if h < 12 # before noon
    ampm = "AM"
    if h = 0
      h = 12
    end
  else     # (after) noon
    ampm =  "PM"
    if h > 12
      h -= 12
    end
  end
  ampm = h <= 12 ? "AM" : "PM";
  return "#{h}:#{m}#{ampm}"
end
```

the Time solution:

```
def toClock(secs)
  t = Time.gm(2000,1,1) + secs   # date doesn't matter but has to be valid
  return "#{t.strftime("%I:%M%p")}   # copy of your desired format
end
```

HTH

Answer (score 2):

In other solutions, the hour-counter would be reset to 00 when crossing 24-hour day boundaries. Also beware that `Time.at` rounds down, so it will give the wrong result if the input has any fractional seconds (f.ex. when `t=479.9` then `Time.at(t).utc.strftime("%H:%M:%S")` will give `00:07:59` and not 00:08:00` which is the correct one).

If you want a way to convert any number of seconds (even high counts larger than 24-hour day spans) into an ever increasing HH:MM:SS counter, and handle potential fractional seconds, then try this:

```
# Will take as input a time in seconds (which is typically a result after subtracting two Time objects),
# and return the result in HH:MM:SS, even if it exceeds a 24 hour period.
def formatted_duration(total_seconds)
  total_seconds = total_seconds.round # to avoid fractional seconds potentially compounding and messing up seconds, minutes and hours
  hours = total_seconds / (60*60)
  minutes = (total_seconds / 60) % 60 # the modulo operator (%) gives the remainder when leftside is divided by rightside. Ex: 121 % 60 = 1
  seconds = total_seconds % 60
  [hours, minutes, seconds].map do |t|
    # Right justify and pad with 0 until length is 2. 
    # So if the duration of any of the time components is 0, then it will display as 00
    t.round.to_s.rjust(2,'0')
  end.join(':')
end
```

Modified from @springerigor's and suggestion in the discussion at https://gist.github.com/shunchu/3175001

Comment: Nicely done! I ended up rolling my own that utilized `ActiveSupport::Duration.build( seconds ).parts` but I like yours so much because it's simpler and doesn't require a Rails that I'm scrapping mine and replacing it with yours. Thanks for posting!

Comment: I also cross-posted to this gist, which seemed to get a lot of traction: https://gist.github.com/shunchu/3175001#gistcomment-3552126

Comment: Whoops, my bad. Didn't realize it was the same gist. I've gone ahead and removed my comment on that Gist. Thanks again.